# How can I run dart code in the background in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, background-process, flutter-dependencies

I want to run a method in my main.dart file from the android(Kotlin) part of my app. For this I am using methodChannels and it works perfectly fine when the app is in foreground. However, the moment the app is killed, the flutterView is destroyed and therefore I am unable to run any methods in my main.dart file.

I read that using FlutterNativeView would allow me to do what I want but I am unable to find small code snippets to help me with it.

It would be great if you could help me with this

Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly do you need to do through dart code which you can't do by Kotlin code in background?

Comment: Hi @SanjaySharma. I need to send background location data to firebase. I could not find any implementation to this in Kotlin and hence the question. It would really great of you could help me run the dart code or tell me a way to send data to firebase when the app is killed from Kotlin?

Comment: Which firebase service are you using?

Comment: realtime database

Comment: You can easily find native code for Firebase realtime db interaction. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

Comment: Thank you so much @SanjaySharma. Writing native Kotlin code worked!!!! This solved my issue! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the native code for Firebase realtime database. You can check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start).
You should create a custom plugin and put the native code in that plugin as writing the files directly in the Flutter `android` folder will make the project unmanageable in the future and you can face multiple unexpected issues.

Answer (score 3):

[In Flutter, you can execute Dart code in the background.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)

The mechanism for this feature involves setting up an isolate. Isolates are Dart’s model for multithreading, though an isolate differs from a conventional thread in that it doesn’t share memory with the main program. You’ll set up your isolate for background execution using callbacks and a callback dispatcher.

[For more information and a geofencing example that uses background execution of Dart code, see the Medium article by Ben Konyi, Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124). At the end of this article, you’ll find links to example code, and relevant documentation for Dart, iOS, and Android.

Comment: Hi @san thanks for your answer! I think isolates and ports should do the job but I solved my issue by writing native Kotlin code. Thanks again!